# How to execute an instruction when loop ends in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

how can I achieve that the instruction

```
 printf(" ");
```

is triggered then the loop ends? I have to write a program for my course which replaces all tab and space with a single space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a;

    while (a != EOF) 
    {
        a=getchar();
        while (a==" " || a=="\t")
            a=EOF;
        /*I want to put printf(" "); here */
        putchar(a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the end of which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your question, I think your posted code won't compile or maby will compile but with warnings.

Let's go through it:

```
int a;
while (a != EOF)
```

Here you are accessing `a` without initializing it, this may lead to unpredictable behavior of your program, you probably better write something like:

```
int a = getchar();
while (a != EOF)
```

Next:

```
while (a==" " || a=="\t")
```

`a` is of type `int` while `""` indicate null terminated string in C and are treated as a *pointer* the the memory where this string is stored. comparing character with a pointer is not a good idea :). What you meant is to compare `a` against space or tab as a **single** character. This should be done by `''`:

```
while (a==' ' || a=='\t')
```

So now we get

```
while (a==' ' || a=='\t')
    a=EOF;
```

This loop will be executed as long as `a` either tab or space but what is in the loop body? `a = EOF;`, so the flow will exit the while loop immediately on the next iteration.
I guess that what you meant is to read input and skip forward as long as the input is either space or tab so you probably have to read the input through `getchar()`

```
while (a==' ' || a=='\t')
    a = getchar();
```

but don't forget that `getchar()` may return `EOF` on end of input or an error and you don't want to get stuck inside this while loop when that happens:

```
while ((a != EOF) && (a==' ' || a=='\t'))
    a = getchar();
```

Now when you exit this `while` loop, unlike in your current code, before printing `a` you need to check if you had spaces or tabs before that and then print a single tab before printing the value in `a`. How (?), **as per your original question**, a couple of options: `printf(" ");` or `putchar(' ');`, choose what you like the most. And also you don't want to print `a` if it contains `EOF`, right? I will leave this part to you for the proper implementation.

Hope it helped and good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is incorrect for multiple reasons:

- `a` is unitialized when you first compare it to `EOF`, so the behavior is undefined.
- you cannot meaningfully compare a character `a` with a string `" "`. Compare `a` to a character constant with single quotes: `a == ' '`.
- you do not read further characters when you detect a space or tab
- you only want to print the space when there is a sequence of white space.

Here is a different approach: read one character at a time, if it is a space, set a space indicator, if not output the character preceded by a space if the indicator is set and reset the indicator.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    int insert_space = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
            insert_space = 1;
        } else {
            if (insert_space) {
                putchar(' ');
                insert_space = 0;
            }
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    if (insert_space) {
        /* there are spaces and/or tabs at the end of the last line
         *  of the file, which is not newline terminated. It might be
         *  a good idea to remove these completely.
         */
        putchar(' ');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run with its own source code as input, the output is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 int c;
 int insert_space = 0;

 while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
 if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
 insert_space = 1;
 } else {
 if (insert_space) {
 putchar(' ');
 insert_space = 0;
 }
 putchar(c);
 }
 }
 if (insert_space) {
 /* there are spaces and/or tabs at the end of the last line
 * of the file, which is not newline terminated. It might be
 * a good idea to remove these completely.
 */
 putchar(' ');
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: :) I see a small bug here... For input like "`abc    `" no space will be printed at the end.

Comment: @chux That's what I meant, `abc   `*EOF*

Comment: @AlexLop.: I did add a note regarding this issue. It is easy to fix the behavior with an extra test after the `while` loop, but it is also important to teach the OP that not all text files end with a newline.

Comment: yes, later I noticed the note at the end of your answer. Anyway good answer especially that what I thought as a bug is documented.

Comment: This one does not quite work, but if we combine it with what Alex Lop said, it works. (The last piece of code he wrote in his answer, then set s (insert_space) to 1 while in the loop.)

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: What do you mean by *This one does not quite work*? The program performs exactly as stated in your question: it *replaces all tab and spaces with a single space.*  The last test ensures that any spaces or tabs present at the end of the file get replaced by a single space.

Comment: @chqrlie It didn´t work asintended as I used it, it just removed a single space or tab. This one does work, however. `#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int a, s=0;
while(a!=EOF) {
a=getchar();
while((a!=EOF)&&(a==' ' || a=='\t')){
s=1;
a=getchar();}
if (s){
putchar(' ');
s=0;} 
putchar(a);}
if (s)
putchar(' ');
return 0;}`

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: you must have tested something else, it does change any sequence of spaces and tabs to a single space. The code in your comment has undefined behavior: `a` is uninitialized and the code seems nested incorrectly.

Comment: @chqrlie Might be, but it works. You don´t actually have to initialize a variable. You just need to assign a value before you use it for something else.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: where do you assign a value before use: `int a, s=0; while(a!=EOF)`

Comment: @chqrlie I assign it here: `a=getchar()` a will not be EOF at the beginning since it is initialized with a random value, like every local variable. Try printing a variable with no value assigned. If it is global, you get 0 (not EOF), if it is local, something like 46903051 or 32963693 might get printed, but never EOF, so the program will enter the loop.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: I'm afraid you are mistaken. Local variables are indeed uninitialized, which means even using their value is undefined behavior. How can you be so sure that it cannot be `EOF` by coincidence?

Comment: @chqrlie I thought it would not be EOF. If it can be EOF, the probability is about 1/4294967294.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: experience tends to show that special values such as `0` and `-1` occur far more often than their statistical expectation...

Comment: Maybe that´s just some random results or it is easier for the CPU to calculate it, so it occurs more often statistically. But is EOF actually a possible value for an unassigned local variable?

Comment: @FantasyCookie17: are you joking? Of course it is. Murphy's law makes it even likely.